# Writing the data frame to MySql DB table

Tags: mysql, r

How to write the data frame in `R` into `MySQL`?

```
dateTime            host    authId     sessionId      status                    action 
2012-08-22 14:58:23 foo.com 221501398 2c10b368ae23ba3        questions#instant_answers
2012-08-22 14:58:23 foo.com 221501398 22c10b368ae23                      questions#new
2012-08-22 14:58:23 foo.com 221501398 01a36f64bd3f80c                     sessions#new
```

I want to write the dataframe all at once to the `MySQL` DB table.
I have used `RMySql` package to connect and establish the connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use the dbWriteTable function. It looks like this :

```
dbWriteTable(connection, value = data.frame, name = "MyTable", append = TRUE )
```

The function is well documented.

P.S
Also look at:
[RMySQL dbWriteTable with field.types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864174/rmysql-dbwritetable-with-field-types)

Comment: It didn't worked to me. The correct syntax is dbWriteTable(connection, "MyTable", data.frame, append = TRUE). The docs: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf

Comment: Adding `row.names=FALSE` will help seamless transfer

Answer (score 7):

See `help(dbSendQuery)` for generic `update ...` statements in SQL, and `help(dbWriteTable)` to write an entire data frame to a new table.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using the command below. Note that this will append the rows in `yourtable` to the database named `yourTableInMySQL`.

```
library(RMySQL)
dbWriteTable(con, "yourTableinMySQL", yourtable, append = TRUE)
```

Comment: I've spent hours without success trying to run DBI's function of the same name. However, RmySQL::dbWiteTable worked immediately.