# R: RJDBC: use dbWriteTable with db2 to specify field types

Tags: sql, r, db2, rjdbc

I am trying to write an R data frame to a table in a db2 data base. Does anyone know what additional argument I supply to the function `dbWriteTable` in order to specify the field types of the columns?

I found this similar question: [RMySQL dbWriteTable with field.types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864174/rmysql-dbwritetable-with-field-types), however, the solution doesn't seem to hold for db2.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't supply fields types using `dbWriteTable`. JDBC is designed to hold many data bases, so it has a minimal data types mapping :

```
   integer --> INTEGER
   numeric --> DOUBLE PRECISION
   else    --> VARCHAR(255)
```

You should create you table using some sql request.