# How to convert a column to BLOB in R before exporting it into MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, database, blob

I am exporting a 2GB data frame from R to MySQL. My each column is having so many values. While exporting Data from R to MySQL i am getting following error:

```
 could not run statement: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.
```

command i used:

```
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = 'tablename', value = as.data.frame(cc))
```

I am using RMySQL package to export data to MySQL database. I didn't already create table in MySQL database. I am directly creating table from R.
Can I change the column's class type to BLOB in R?
How to deal with it?

Comment: More details needed. "exporting Data from R to MySQL" - how? using a particular package in R? what package? what command?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it is a little hard to tell, but I believe you can pass the `field.types` variable into `dbWriteTable`. See `?mysqlBuildTableDefinition` for a description of `field.types` - it should be a named list with the data types. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864174/rmysql-dbwritetable-with-field-types) may also help you.

e.g. if your column is called `bigblob` you would do

```
dbWriteTable(conn=con, name='tablename', value=as.data.frame(cc),
             field.types=list(bigblob='BLOB',
                              # types for all your other columns too
             ))
```

I believe if you specify the type for one column, you must specify the types for all the others too.